# Writing XML in C# - 'Token StartElement in state Epilog would result in an invalid XML document' error

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to write to an XML document, taking data from an ArrayList of lists

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            string headname = (headers[0] as List<string>)[i];
                headname.Replace("&", "&amp;");
                headname.Replace("<", "&lt;");
                headname.Replace(">", "&gt;");
                headname.Replace("\"", "&quot;");
                headname.Replace("'", "&apos;");
            textWriter.WriteStartElement("MetadataName", "");
            textWriter.WriteString(headname);
            textWriter.WriteEndElement();
```

The problem I'm having is that after it goes through the for loop once, i get a 'Token StartElement in state Epilog would result in an invalid XML document' error on the line with WriteStartElement, and I've tried looking up how to fix it and have not really had any breakthroughs. Thanks.

EDITED for update.

Comment: Your original code shows a problem this does not please put back the framing code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
textWriter.WriteStartElement("Metadata Name", "");
```

An element name cannot contain spaces. Try this:

```
textWriter.WriteStartElement("MetadataName", "");
```

I am assuming that the data in your `headers` array is well formed for XML (for example, all `&` are escaped to `&amp;` etc...).

Additionally, as Mark notes in his answer, you need to make sure the XML is rooted - that is, that there is a root element in which you put your `MetadataName` elements.

Read about [well formed XML](http://www.developer.com/net/vb/article.php/797861/Well-Formed-XML.htm) and what that means - you need to make sure your document is well formed, as you build it up.

Comment: I did as you said; removed spaces from names, and changed bad characters, but i must be doing something wrong or have something wrong in my array, because I still get the error.

Answer (score 9):

An XML document will have a root element ie one that includes all other elements. You don't have one

Your doc is like

```
<MetadataName><header0/><header1/></MetadataName>
<MetadataName><header0/><header1/></MetadataName>
```

An XML doc is like

```
<root>
    <MetadataName><header0/><header1/></MetadataName>
    <MetadataName><header0/><header1/></MetadataName>
</root>
```

You need to WriteStartElement and WriteEndElement around your loop

Comment: Thank you! It saves now; Next thing to do is make it valid XML.